# App rejections concerns for iphone app store

Tags: app-store

Will an app get rejected if you have a button that opens a page in safari? And if so how can I avoid this?

Comment: Errr... There's nothing wrong with that. Where did you get that notion from?

Comment: I keep getting my app rejected my app passed everything except the reviewers says it lack user interaction since my first submission was consider gathering information so I took the app reviewer advice and add website to the app. Now I hope I don't get rejected so I am taking caution.

Comment: There's the HIG guidelines, ever read that?

Comment: No need to get ranty on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't get rejected. These buttons occur all the time. There are even buttons that open safari links that redirect to the appstore. They have a new rule that you're not suppose to have links advertising other people's apps, but that's being looked into.

Edit: Yes it is a strange question to ask (where did you get the notion). I should note, they have a problem with redirecting to external app stores. If you want payment, it has to be in app.

Comment: thank you, also, what is the point of web view if we can open links in safari?

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to user to leave your app. Lets say you have a game, and there's a forum. Players want to be able to read the forums in game. Sometimes, you may want to open in safari; maybe you're redirecting them to an external website (cannot think of a concrete example atm).